# Flutter: Why is this class not recognized as a class?

Tags: android, class, dart

I'm new to Flutter, so maybe it's a very small thing. I'm creating a class, but the class is not recognized as a class:

```
class CamPage extends StatefulWidget {
      ...
}

class _CamPageState extends State<CamPage> {
      ...
}
```

When I do this in Main.dart:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new CamPage(title: 'Title'),
      );
  }
}
```

it says: `Undefined class 'CamPage'`

I left out the code in the `CamPage` class because it is not relevant, it is not the problem. I have a different class, `MyHomePage`, and if I call it in exactly the same way in main.dart it will work. If I copy and paste this working class code exactly to `CamPage`, and only change the name of the class, it still doesn't work.

So `MyHomePage` works, and `CamPage` doesn't work. While they contain the exact same code, only the class name is different.

I made `MyHomePage` a few days ago, and `CamPage` just today. In the meantime, Android Studio has been updated, and the project has been linked to git. Could the problem be related to that? Now when I create a new Dart file, I am asked if I want to add the file to git as well. If I click `yes`, the name of the Dart file appears in green letters everywhere. If I click `no`, the name of that Dart file turns red everywhere. These green and red files are not working. `MyHomePage`, the Dart file that was previously created, is still in black letters and it works.

So, the question is: Why is `MyHomePage` working (and black), and why is `CamPage` not working (and green).

Does anyone know where this could be? See picture. So `MyHomePage` and `CamPage` contain exactly the same code, that's not the problem. Very weird.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX2qW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The changing colors of the file names is related to git, green files are newly created files since the last commit that are not yet committed, blue files are existing files from the last commit that have active changes, and black files are unchanged files.

As for your problem, without more information, double check that you have imported your CamPage in main.dart like you import MyHomePage. If that isnt the problem please add more code or errors shown in android studio.